# How to bind custom event handler from vue-touch-events to a custom component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currently implementing a classical Minesweeper game in Vue.js which is working fine so far https://github.com/franktopel/defuse, Demo http://connexo.de/defuse/.

[image: Screenshot of Defuse Game]

Now I would like to add touch support because as of now, to mark a field as "contains a mine" it is required that you right-click the field. Right-clicking is obviously not available on touch devices, so I would like to add `longtap` support. I'm using native events `click` and `click.right` from the parent component for each field, so the field does not handle the events, but the parent component that instantiates these fields does.

I've found this https://github.com/jerrybendy/vue-touch-events and added it to my project, yet it seems I cannot use this on the component tag (see https://github.com/franktopel/defuse/blob/master/src/components/Defuse.vue):

```
    <m-field
      v-for="field in row"
      :field="field"
      :key="`${field.x},${field.y}`"
      @click.native="open(field)"
      @click.right.native.prevent="toggleBombMarker(field)"
      v-touch:longtap="toggleBombMarker(field)"
    ></m-field>
```

because that marks all fields without any user interaction and the console keeps producing

```
You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

This is how my `field` objects (which I'm passing to the field component) are created:

```
let Field = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.isOpen = false
  this.hasBomb = false
  this.isMarked = false
  this.numNeighbourBombs = null
}

module.exports = Field
```

I have also tried emitting a custom event from inside my field component, yet I don't know how I can pass the triggering field to the event handler from there.

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you using the `v-touch` directive correctly? See [How to add extra parameters](https://github.com/jerrybendy/vue-touch-events#how-to-add-extra-parameters).

Comment: That seems to solve the problem, if you state that as an answer and add some explanation, I'll be more than glad to make you score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `vue-touch-events` [docs](https://github.com/jerrybendy/vue-touch-events#how-to-add-extra-parameters), the `v-touch` directive doesn't work in the same way as `v-on`; `v-touch` must be given a function to execute, whereas the `toggleBombMarker(field)` expression probably returns `undefined`.

If you want to pass extra parameters to the `v-touch` handler, your handler must return a function like this:

```js
methods: {
  toggleBombMarker(field) {
    return () => {
      // your handler code here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me solve it. I added `v-touch:longtap="emitLongtap(field)"` inside the `field` component, as well as a `method` `emitLongtap (field) {
        return () => {
          this.$emit('longtap', field)
        }
      }`. In the parent component I put a `<field @longtap="toggleBombMarker(field)" />`